# In computer science Using the digit 4 exactly four times and 4 signs only and only the operation + is allowed how to get 10?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

in computer science Using the digit  4 exactly four times and 4 signs only and only the operation + is allowed how to get 10?

for example:

> $(44 - 4) / 4 = 10$

does not work because 44 is a number and not the digit 4,and we used a - not just +.

> $4+4+4-\sqrt{4}=10$

is a wrong answer even though we have 4 digits of 4 and 4 operations but we used a - and sqrt opération not just +.

Thanks for your response to solve this puzzle.

Comment: I think you need to clarify "4 signs only" with "only the operation +".  Do you mean that you are not only limited to addition, but also only 4 additions maximum?

Comment: Simple question simple answer only the + operation is allowed

Comment: Okay - so the only way out of this is to not use base 10? (as i see that @xhienne has just posted lol)

Comment: do you have another answer given apart from my answer?

Comment: 10 is a number here and 4 is a digit

Comment: In your second counter-example, there is no objection to using the square root. Nonetheless, I assume square root is not allowed.

Comment: if you can find a solution for 10 and 4 in base 10 different from mine, I would like to see it.

Comment: I think the problem is that your proposed solution goes against your comment above.  In your solution 4 is *not only* a digit, but also the (not-advisable) name of a function that has nothing to do with the digit 4.

Comment: and then I can not name f (letter) 4 (a digit) no contradiction with the question

Comment: I think that your answer in comment to @xhienne shows the confusion you are causing by mixing up mathematical terms like "sign", "operation" and "digit".  Your answer is also trading on mixing the definitions up.

Comment: Yes but even in the mixture my question is well formulated mathematically, and with the data processing I could program that.his answer is correct but I can not tell the difference between +4 and 4 in programming

Comment: There is no difference - and I am not responding to these comments anymore.  However, if you wanted this to be only valid in programming there is a tag for that.  (And unary + *is* valid when programming in almost all programming languages... starting a function name with a digit, however, is not.)

Comment: @Graylocke My understanding is that a sign is anything but a digit. What is less clear to me is that ! and √ seem to not be operations (but I'm no mathematician).

Comment: Let the function 4(x) for x real such that 4(44)=6 for x=44. 4(44)+4=10, since the equal sign is also a sign. If you say the equal sign doesn't count, then I can say "let the function 4(x) for x real such that 4(4+4)=6 for x=4+4. 4(4+4)+4=10.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because the question and the self-answer combined makes it unclear exactly which operations are allowed and which are not.

Comment: @Prince North Læraðr  44 is number not digit

Comment: @Extrazlove Even if I were to grant you that, my second answer is correct according to your reasoning.

Comment: No 4   4 is different 44 ,use only digit 4 in question and you usd number 44

Comment: "let the function 4(x) for x real such that 4(4+4)=6 for x=4+4. 4(4+4)+4=10" does not use 44

Comment: 4 + 4. 4 (4 + 4) + 4 = 10 you used  6 for 4 and . et sings>4

Comment: No, I'm defining 4(4+4) as equal to 6. I can make the inside of a function equal to anything I want, especially if it's as vague as yours

Comment: Well, go answer it to the question is to test if you use 4 and 4 signs and only the + operation.
Write this formula that verfies this

Comment: And how does my formula not verify that? I followed all of your "rules". I used 4 4's. I used 4 "signs". I only used the + operation.

Comment: 4 + 4. 4 (4 + 4) + 4 = 10     6 four used and  + . + + ( )  not used . and sings=6>4

Comment: No, the equation is 4(4+4)+4=10

Comment: And defined the function as 4(4+4)=6

Comment: yes it is correct sorry I am not much I used a corrector.4 (4 + 4) + 4 = 10 with 4(4+4)=6 et 4() is fonction 4(8)=6

Comment: a used 4(4+4+4)=10 with 4() and 4(12)=10 is correct.

Comment: Which goes to show why this question is being closed

Comment: is there just 3 possible answer is there any other?

Comment: without seeing my answer i don't think you would have found the second answer

Comment: I gave a good question and a bad example not to follow.
Is there an error in this question?

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use

> [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (base 16):
>
>  +4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 10

Comment: +4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4  ???

Comment: Added a link to hexadecimal if you are not familiar with base 16

Comment: you used no sign just the + operation

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is a sign exactly? Where are the four "signs" in your examples?

Comment: !, squart < > ( )....and + and not - not * and not / for question.

Comment: OK, so ((+4 + 4 + 4 + 4)) = 10 would be OK for you? Or should I add any more "signs" to the equation?

Comment: you have used 4 + and and four signs () and the question asks to use at most 4 (sign and operation +) not 8.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. I don't see anything in your question that asks to use at least one sign that is not an operation. Moreover, in my answer, I used four "signs". The first is the "plus sign" and the three others are additions.

Comment: it's for a purpose to speed up my computer, yes it's true your answer is correct but I do not see as programming +4 and the difference between 4 in programming

Comment: TBH - the use of the unary + is *at least* as valid as naming a function "4" and defining it "outside the puzzle" to have the value 2.

Comment: he does the same with a hexadecimal 4 ,just his demonstration gives 4 and 3 signs at the same time.and the question wants 4 exact sign not 4 or 3

Comment: Reminds me of hexomino.

Comment: @Extrazlove Please stop with this non-sense! **Just read my answer again and count the signs**. There are 4 plus signs. Four! Not 3, not "4 or 3", not "4 and 3 at the same time", just 4, no more no less. You are creating a confusion out of nowhere by writing mysterious nonsensical comments like "you used no sign just the + operation", by refusing that I prefix a number with a "+", [which is of common use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Plus_sign) or by adding extra constrains like the speed of your computer or your programming language. I give up.

Comment: @riskymysteries Hope you are referring to "hexadecimal" and not the OP's behavior.

Comment: @xhienne 4 signs only (+4 + 4 + 4 + 4 is 4 signs and +4 + 4 + 4 + 4=4 + 4 + 4 + 4 is 3 signs) +4 + 4 + 4 + 4 is 4 signs or 3 sings not only 4 signs.

Comment: @Extrazlove Just read my answer again and count the signs

Comment: @xhienne *Of course* I'm referring to "hexadecimal"!

Comment: (+ )logic gate not connected to anything, how do you pass the current to close the circuit with this (+) more you have to add 0 to pass the electric current is( +) 4 + 4 + 4 = 10 we cannot program it in program rather 0 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 10
sorry i use a translator

Comment: @Extrazlove The very fact that you cannot bring a simple answer to the question "how many signs are in my answer" (electric current??? logic gate??? program???), although this is your own puzzle, your own rules and your own definition of "sign", demonstrates that your problem is ill-posed. That is why your question is now closed. This is my last message. Have a good day.

Comment: @xhienne I modified the question is it clear ? :in computer science Using the digit 4 exactly four times and 4 signs only and only the operation + is allowed how to get 10?

Answer (score 0):

As OP's examples seem to not object to anything but `-`, how about

> $\frac{4 \times 4 + 4}{\sqrt 4}$ or (same thing) $\frac{4^{\sqrt 4} + 4}{\sqrt 4}$?

Comment: no you did not only use the +, there is / and *

Comment: In your examples you do use `/` and `\sqrt` and do not object to either @Extrazlove.

Comment: I just gave wrong answers not to follow and why

Answer (score -8):

Let the function  $4 (x)$  for  $x$   real such that  $4 (4) = 2$  for   $ x = 4$.

So we have $4 (4) + 4 + 4 = 10.$

there are $4$ digits to use, and for signs $($ and $)$ and $+$ and$ +$, and only the $+$ to used.

Comment: Is x real or is x a function?

Comment: I do as a matter of principle never downvote, but for this I was very close to making an exception.

Comment: @jay 4 is simple a function yes x real.

Comment: Ha ha. Very funny.

Comment: @jay answer to this question is only 3
4(x) >>4(4)=2>>4(4)+4+4=10 or 4(4+4)=6 >>4(4+4)+4=10  or 4(4+4+4)=10.